# What is the correct way to reference a resource dictionary?

Tags: wpf

In my application, I tend to reference my resource dictionaries using a relative path, like so:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ResourceDictionaries/SplashScreen.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

However, for one of the libraries I use in my application, (Fluent) the reference to the resource dictionaries I need are different (I believe they're called Pack URI's or something?):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Fluent;component/Themes/Office2013/Generic.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Color x:Key="{x:Static Fluent:MetroColors.ThemeColorKey}">#60327A</Color>
        <vm:MainWindowViewModel x:Key="MainWindowViewModel" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Is there a 'correct' way I should be referencing my resource dictionaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pack URIs are required when the resource is in a different assembly than the one being compiled.

The Fluent URI references the Fluent assembly.
pack://application:,,,/**Fluent**;component/Themes/Office2013/Generic.xaml

In theory you could reference the current assembly, but I never use them unless I have to because they're such a pain to get right!

Answer (score 1):

The difference is because a URI is used for accessing embedded resources, linked files, or loose files. However the URI may look different, depending on what type of resource is being accessed.

The "pack URI," with the three commas in it, is set up differently from the first URI, because the resource's *source* is a different type.

For more info, see this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) article.

Comment: What type of resource is being accessed? Are they not both Resource Dictionaries?

Comment: Sorry, my answer is confusing. I've changed to say pack URI is different because the resource *source* is a different type.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks.